# SQL Server 2012 Subprocesses

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a "If EXISTS" Query in my Code. On the Cases I do a Insert into Statement with different Values. My idea is, that the Statement runing in a Subprocess like

```
goto MySubPro(Value1, Value2)
Sub MySubPro

Insert into ...

End Sub
```

But i get an Error like: Wrong Syntax near by "Sub"
All Information i found in Web are describe the Select Subprocess, but i will run different diferent code in the Subprocess and come back to the mainprocess..
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: can you please explain more ..

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have "Subs" (that's VB land)... Perhaps you mean Stored Procedures? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx

Comment: I have read someting about Sub Process. I think i must change to Stored Procedures. Is there anythink near by VBs Word Subs outside Stored Procedures?

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server doesn't have 'Subs', like previously mentioned that is VB. If you want want to create a stored procedure along the lines of the logic you're currently using, it would be something like

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spFoo
  @Value1 INT,
  @Value2 INT

AS

INSERT INTO...;
```

Then you would run that to create your stored procedure, and then be able to execute it

```
EXEC spFoo @Value1=x, @Value2=y;
```

Or more simply

```
EXEC spFoo x y;
```

Comment: ...and that SP can call other SPs; this may have been the source of OP's 'sub process' reference.